# How are array elements accessed in summing function?

Tags: octave

I'm attempting to implement below algorithm in Octave :

[image]

Code for this algorithm :

```matlab
    x = [1
2
3
]

    y = [4,5,6]



m = length(y)

x = [ones(m , 1) , x]

theta = zeros(2, 1);        
printf(mat2str(theta , 2))
sprintf('%f' , theta)

iterations = 5;
alpha = 0.07;

for iter = 1:iterations
     theta
     theta = theta -((1/m) * ((x * theta) - y)' * x)' * alpha;
end
```

How is each individual value of `y` accessed, as code above appears to be accessing the entire `y` matrix within each iteration ?

Is there some implicit functionality concurring which allows to just use `y` and not use something like `y[i]` where `i` is the current iteration ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever a sum take looks like

```
sum(a_i * b_i, for i = 1 ... m)
```

it can be re-written as a dot product between vectors

```
A^T * B
```

with A and B being vectors of size m.
In the algorithm description, they use the first formulation, in the code, it's the second.

```
(x * theta) - y)' * x
```

is the dot product between vectors `(x * theta) - y)` and `x`.